# Why does using multiple PRNGs concurrently yield biased results?

Tags: python, random

```
import random as r
from random import Random
from threading import Thread
#ap = amount of random points
#load_split = how many threads are tasked with it
def pi(ap=1000000,load_split=16):
#circle hits
    c,=0,
#chooses a random point and sees if it is in the circle
    def t(seed,ap=ap/load_split):
        nonlocal c
        r = Random()
        r.seed(seed)
        while ap>0:
            if ((r.random()-0.5)**2+(r.random()-0.5)**2)**0.5<=0.5: c+=1
            ap-=1
    th = []
    for i in range(load_split):
        thr = Thread(target=t,args=[r.random()*i])
        thr.start()
        th.append(thr)
#executes the random tries lost to the threads
    for i in range(ap%load_split): 
        if ((r.random()-0.5)**2+(r.random()-0.5)**2)**0.5<=0.5: c+=1
#waiting for threads to complete
    for i in th: i.join()
    return 4 * c / ap
input(pi())
```

Why do the approximated pi values get smaller when I distribute the load over more threads?

First I thought it may be because of using the same seed, so I generate differently seeded local `Random`s for each `Thread`, which each seed being randomised as well instead of just being incrementing integer values.
(Even though I don't think the latter part made the difference)

But the problem still persists. Does anyone know the reason for that behaviour?

Comment: Why do you call `input(pi())`?

Comment: What do you mean by "approximated pi values get smaller"? You mean they get closer to the correct value?

Comment: Maybe it's because of `ap=ap/load_split`. So `ap` is smaller with more threads.

Comment: You probably need a mutex around the increments of `c`.

Comment: i run it from explorer, so i input() prevents the window from closing.

Comment: no, i mean they get smaller in value

Comment: yes, the ap/load_split is to reduce the load on the main thread, so it's supposed to get smaller

Comment: mutex? probably, i just conveniently thought thread safety is already guaranteed in python because of the convenient design i already experienced from the language. looking into it now

Comment: I tried it with 16, 32, and 64 threads. The results I got were 2.748732
2.395884
2.75288

Comment: A second test adding 200 threads produced: 2.979836
2.076516
2.679564
3.142104

Comment: With 100, 200, 300, 400 threads the results were 2.667636
3.14018
3.143712
3.143656

Comment: maybe it's at a resource limit at the very high thread counts so it optimizes the accesses to proper intervals again, my non-scientific guess

Comment: but these locks, when they are locked and another thread calls acquire, is it in an infinite while loop only breaking if the unlocked condition is met? isnt that quite cpu heavy and go against the purpose of spreading the load

Comment: The benefit of multi-threading depends on how often the threads need to access shared resources. The more independent computations they can do, the more you gain.

Comment: In your case, it depends on how the time spent waiting for the lock compares to calling `r.random()` twice.

Comment: Well, now I let the threads use a list. Doens't speed it up significantly for my purposes tho, since it's still in the multiple seconds and I want it to complete almost instantaneously.
For the lock.acquire vs r.random, doesnt that not matter? Because even if I put the lock in front of the r.random, after the lock releases the r.random still needs to be called, while the other way round it just doesnt need to increment, thus dont needing the lock.

Comment: The lock should only be around `c += 1`. That's the only shared resource.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021882/make-the-random-module-thread-safe-in-python

Comment: Since you create a new `Random` instance in each thread, it's already thread-safe, so you don't need the mutex around `r.random()`.

Comment: Yes, I already made the random thread-safe in a previous edit iteration, as stated in the question. I tried the lock around the read/write of the assignment operator, but after all I decided to just let each thread use it's own slot in a list to make them independent. Still thank you for pointing out the major point in my problem, which was assuming python was default thread-safe or at least had its built-ins or primitives thread-safe, because I am used to the simplicity feel of the language.

Comment: You should post your final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random as r
from random import Random
from threading import Thread
def pi(ap=8000000,load_split=4):
    c=[]
    for i in range(load_split): c.append(0)
#now each thread writes to its own circle hit count
    def t(seed,ap=ap/load_split):
        r = Random()
        r.seed(seed)
        while ap>0:
            if ((r.random()-0.5)**2+(r.random()-0.5)**2)**0.5<=0.5:
                c[seed]+=1
            ap-=1
    th = []
    for i in range(load_split):
        thr = Thread(target=t,args=[i])
        thr.start()
        th.append(thr)
    for i in range(ap%load_split): 
        if ((r.random()-0.5)**2+(r.random()-0.5)**2)**0.5<=0.5: c+=1
    for i in th: i.join()
    return 4 * sum(c) / ap
input(pi())
```